# Should I spend a year studying computer science in my home nation, when I am already interested in a master's in a foreign nation?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, learning

Spending a year in my home nation to fulfill my dream of studying computer science, although I have an undergraduate degree in computer science, when I'm eventually interested in doing a master's in Computer Science in the USA?

My ultimate goal is to get a masters in the United States and I won't lie, settle there if I get lucky(I know the chance to get a permanent visa is very low for Nepalese). Or Australia, Canada anything is alright as well. I did a computer engineering degree here in Nepal, I got nice grades. I got first division. The order of good students goes as (Distinction, First Division, Second Division, Third division). However, I suffered from some issues that I am not comfortable sharing which (I believe) caused a drop in my performance. I said "drop" because earlier I was scoring a lot in tough courses as well and showed some glimpses of it in my computer engineering degree.

Thankfully, I fell in love with computer science and I can't stop thinking about computer science day and night. I don't know if this is eternal student syndrome or not, but I want to study the core computer science subjects once again. I've allocated a year along with my 9-6 X 5 days a week job. **Which I know is not doable as I've just 2 days free per week where I can study 7 hours each. 14 hours of studying per week isn't going to lead my anywhere. I know that very well.**.

The subjects of my interest(The extent to which I study them are typical university courses level) are:

- Database
- Distributed computing/system and database
- Algorithms
- Computer Architecture
- Computer Networks
- Operating System
- Python using Fred Baptiste course(all 4 of his courses)

Other interests are artificial intelligence, compiler design, and computer graphics. My goal is not to become a data scientist or a software developer. My goal is to work on Linux Administration and eventually transition to DevOps engineering. But I want to be a person who can build software, I want to understand the science of computers and software like a pro topper student in undergraduate. Whenever I try to make a snake game, the concept of data structures comes to give me pain which I've already forgotten. When I've tried to optimize/tune the Linux and MySQL systems, the concept of operating systems class, distributed systems class, database class, and computer architecture class comes and hits me.

So, I want to spend a year in Nepal attempting to learn all these concepts(Which I don't believe is doable). I can't spend more years than 1 because if I do so, my age of marriage will come and I don't want to marry before I am fully independent and the USA(or any European or North American or Australian country) is my opportunity to become independent. I'm 25 right now.

Please guide should I do this? Or should I leave all of this and just start preparing for graduate admissions?

**I know I've to learn English, study GRE :D before I even attempt to move out of Nepal.**

Comment: You are seeking advice in many different areas such as getting into a master's, moving to the US, career transitioning, learning English and even marriage. Stack Exchange sites work better for focused questions.

Comment: None of what you said is my question though. I think it's little bit unclear. My simple question is "should I spend a year self-studying"?

Comment: @Buffy I don't get it really, please explain.

Comment: @barnyard Your question is far too specific for your specific situation, e.g. listing specific courses you have taken, etc. You should distill your question down to something more specific in the question, and more general in the details. E.g., "Will I be more likely to be admitted to a master's in XXX if I do YYY"?

Answer (score 0):

You can spend a year, or a decade, self studying. You can also make a few applications to universities in places you'd like to study. You can do the latter while also working on your self study.

But, you won't know if you are a good applicant until you actually join the process.

Note, however, that a masters in the US is seldom funded; especially in CS. The costs of tuition and living will be high. It wouldn't be a problem if your family has a lot (lot) of resources or if Nepal has a way to provide funding for citizens studying elsewhere.

A decent plan would be to make some applications while also beginning study of English. And English is also used in many other countries than the US.

Comment: No pain, no gain.

Comment: stackexchange is blessed to have you! Thank you for providing answers to our doubts.